# Get Relative Url in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I am using Razor in my views. Due to my IT dept. the app sits at a relative root like `http://ourdomain.com/appRoot` instead of at the top of the domain like `http://ourdomain.com`. The other challenge here is, `appRoot` is not static. It actually changes. For that reason, I need to get the name of the relative root via Razor. Currently, I have something like the following:

```
<input id="hiddenElem" type="hidden" value="12345" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function doThis() {
    var id = $('#hiddenElem').val();
    var nextUrl = '@(Request.?)' + '/path/' + id;
    alert(nextUrl);
  }
</script>
```

When `doThis` is called, I want to see the alert window to display `/appRoot/path/12345`. What do I put into the Razor block associated with `nextUrl` to get the relative root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you would use the `mvc` routing function `Url.Action()`.

```
function doThis() {
    var id = $('#hiddenElem').val();
    var nextUrl = '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")' + '/path/' + id;
    alert(nextUrl);
  }
```

The `Html.ResolveUrl()` function is fine for resolving relative paths, however, it does not take into consideration routing.

Also, using the `Url.Content()` function may produce a result you are expecting. For example, in the snippet below:

```
.Template("<img src='"+ @Url.Content("~/Images/Icons/16/STATE.png")+"'/> <mark>${data.StateName }</mark>");
```

The image will always resolve no matter where you are calling it from or how you accessed the view withing the root.